# Endless loops - not sure why?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone tell me why this script results in an endless loop?

```
    var words = ' ';
var spaces = /\s{9}/;
var p;
p = spaces.test(words);

do {
    words = prompt("Test ", " ");
}
while (p != true);

var array = words.split(" ");
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.write(array[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

do {nothing with p} while (conditional on p) is obviously going to keep running forever. Did you mean this:

```
var words = ' ', spaces = /\s{9}/, p;
do {
   p = spaces.test(words);
   words = prompt("Test ", " ");
}
while (!p);
```

Comment: ... if and only if p is false when you went into the loop

Comment: certainly, but it clearly will be, as ' ' won't match 9 spaces.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks Mike, still stuck though. When I look at the script, to me, it says "check if there are 9 spaces then continue until/unless there are not 9 spaces...re-run the loop". But my browser doesn't see it that way. I'm using Safari on Mac OS....which shouldn't matter for this issue.

Comment: In that case you need to learn to read code with more precision: it actually says to do what's in `do { ... }` until `p` is not truthy, i.e. until the previous `words` request had 9 spaces in it. I suspect you asked question X ("why does this loop") when you're **actually** interested in Y ("how do I get input from the user until that input has 9 spaces"). If so, updating your post will be a great idea.

Comment: @user2494640 Try to invert the order of the lines inside the loop. It should prompt you for a word on every iteration. When you type 9 spaces and press OK, it should break out of the loop.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You should prompt first, then test against the regex, or you'll only break after getting the correct answer and prompting again.

Comment: @bfavaretto: we don't know that. His question wasn't to make his code work, his question was why it endlessly looped. If he actually wanted to know something else, he gets to change his post to reflect his real question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm only pointing out a logic problem in your answer (which BTW I upvoted). Although what the OP wants is unclear, I doubt an extra loop iteration is welcome. Try your code, and type 9 spaces at the prompt; it will prompt again, then break (regardless of what you entered into the second prompt).

Answer (score 2):

You aren't changing P every time you loop. P will always be what it was before you entered the loop

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think the regex does not do what you think it does. \s{9} will search for 9 spaces in a row. regex seems a pretty hard tool to use, so I made what I think you want using split, which it seems you are already familar with.

```
var words = ' ';
var p;

do {
    words = prompt("Test", "");
    p = words.split(" ");
}
while (p.length != 9);

var array = words.split(" ");
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.write(array[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Perhaps?

Comment: still stuck in a loop

Comment: Can you expand on why requester is stuck in a loop and how this solution would fix that?

Comment: @aland Thanks, still seems to be stuck. I'm just going to have to keep working on it. What you have here makes sense, but it doesn't seem to be cooperating.